# getPreferenceScreen() on a null object reference/Why my CheckBoxPreference is null

Tags: java, android, settings

I have a problem with this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app, PID: 8440
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.Settings}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getPreferenceScreen()' on a null object reference
```

this is my Settings class

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {



boolean isWoman;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        isWoman = true;
    } else {
        isWoman= extras.getBoolean("isWoman");
        SettingsFragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        CheckBoxPreference pref = Objects.requireNonNull(fragment.getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("pregnant"));
        pref.setEnabled(isWoman);
    }

}

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
    }
}
```

I've tried to delete getPreferenceScreen() but then I get this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app, PID: 9219
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.Settings}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My question is how can I fix it and why my pref (CheckBoxPreference) is still null?

(Of course, I passed correctly boolean in putextra in the previous activity)

```
settings = findViewById(R.id.settings);
    settings.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MySecoundActivity.this, Settings.class);
        intent.putExtra("isWoman", sharedPreferences.getBoolean("female", false));
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed this problem by doing two methods in the Settings class

```
    //Setting the boolean
   public void setBoolean() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
        isWoman = true;
    } else {
        isWoman = extras.getBoolean("isWoman");
      
    }
 }
 //getting boolean
public boolean getBoolean() {
return isWoman;
}
}
```

I set boolean in onCreate method and later on, I've written this to SettingsFragment

```
Settings settings = new Settings();
    boolean MyBoolean = settings.getBoolean();

            CheckBoxPreference pref = findPreference("pregnant");
    assert pref != null;
    pref.setEnabled(MyBoolean);
```